# how to change paginate response?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

In Laravel no way to replace the default structure for paginated responses. This is the structure I'm trying to achieve:

```
return response()->json([
    'data' => $items->items()
    'meta' => [
        'current_page'   =>   $items->currentPage(),
        'from'           =>   $items->firstItem(),
        'last_page'      =>   $items->lastPage(),
        'per_page'       =>   $items->perPage(),
        'to'             =>   $items->lastItem(),
        'total'          =>   $items->total(),
    ];
]);
```

Comment: any error in the code now

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue before with [resource collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections). This is not supported by Laravel out of the box so it needs a bit of work.

First, you got to override the `App\Http\Resources\PaginatedResourceResponse` class, which is the default way to present paginated response. Then you can override the default structure of the returned paginated data.

```php
class CustomPaginatedResourceResponse extends PaginatedResourceResponse
{
}
```

Then pls create a resource collection that uses the custom paginated resource.

```php
class ItemsResource extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
    }

    // Override the toResponse method.
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $this->resource instanceof AbstractPaginator
            ? (new CustomPaginatedResourceResponse($this))->toResponse($request)
            : parent::toResponse($request);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can simply use the `ItemsResource` in your controller.

```php
return new ItemsResource($items);
```

This requires understanding of the api resources and the source code. Pls spend some time to read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources) and figure out how the `App\Http\Resources\PaginatedResourceResponse` is used.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 10 (not sure since which version) you can implement method `paginationInformation` on your `ResourceCollection` ([Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources#customizing-the-pagination-information)), where you can adjust default format of pagination data. I made class like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection;

class PaginatedJsonResourceCollection extends AnonymousResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Adjust pagination data format
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param array $paginated
     * @param array $default
     * @return array
     */
    public function paginationInformation(Request $request, array $paginated, array $default)
    {
        unset($default['links']);
        $default['meta'] = [
            'page' => $default['meta']['current_page'],
            'lastPage' => $default['meta']['last_page'],
            'perPage' => $default['meta']['per_page'],
            'total' => $default['meta']['total']
        ];

        return $default;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I totally removed `links` attribute from the response and adjusted `meta` field to my needs.

Then I needed to tell Laravel to use this custom class when creating collections so I created `PaginatedJsonResource` class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PaginatedJsonResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Create a new resource collection instance.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $resource
     * @return PaginatedJsonResourceCollection
     */
    protected static function newCollection($resource): PaginatedJsonResourceCollection
    {
        return new PaginatedJsonResourceCollection($resource, static::class);
    }
}
```

And then made all my resources extend this class:

```
class ArticleResource extends PaginatedJsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'content' => $this->content,
        ];
    }
}
```

Now whenever I return in controller

```
return ArticleResource::collection(Article::paginate());
```

I get paginated data in my custom format:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 12345,
      "title": "Article 1",
      "content": "..."
    },
    {
      "id": 12346,
      "title": "Article 2",
      "content": "..."
    },
    ...
  ],
  "meta": {
    "page": 1,
    "lastPage": 50,
    "perPage": 15,
    "total": 1000
  }
}
```